# How to have a single spring scheduler that support multiple timezones?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, spring-scheduled

I have a specific scenario in which I need to run a scheduler at 00:00 AM every day for different timezones. Currently, I am using spring scheduler in fixed rate of 10 minutes so that I will not miss any timezones(Not an ideal solution though!).
But what I need is, I want this scheduler to be running at the specfic time instead of running every 10 minutes. To explain it in detail

- Assume I have 3 time zones: T1, T2 and T3.
- I want the scheduler to be triggered only 3 times a day. 00:00 AM of T1, T2 and T3 respectively.
- I dont want to write 3 schedulers for this because the business logic is the same.

Does springs scheduler provides that flexibility of running a scheduler at different timezones?
If it doesn't are there any library out there which does this job for us?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using quartz to create triggers based on crons. Spring has a native support for quartz with spring-boot-starter-quartz dependency. I would start with this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule and https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-batch/batch-quartz-java-config-example for spring batch incase you are interested in batch
Quartz supports multiple triggers too for a single job.